# requireJS e JQuery causando problemas de dependencia

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, requirejs

Eu estou tentando aplicar o requireJS na minha aplicação, poré, estou tendo alguns problemas.

require-config.js

```
var require = {
    paths: {
        "jquery": "/admin/admin-v2/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
        "bootstrap": "/admin/admin-v2/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min",
        "metismenu": "/admin/admin-v2/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min",
        "morris": "/admin/admin-v2/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.min",
        "raphael": "/admin/admin-v2/bower_components/raphael/raphael-min",
        "morrisdata": "/admin/admin-v2/controllers/js/morris-data",
        "datatables": "/admin/admin-v2/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
        "datatablesbootstrap": "/admin/admin-v2/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min",
        "global": "/admin/admin-v2/js/sb-admin-2"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            deps: [],
            exports: '$'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'metismenu': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'raphael': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'Raphael'
        },
        'morris': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'raphael'],
            exports: 'Morris'
        },
        'morrisdata': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'morris']
        },
        'datatables': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'fatatablesbootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'datatables', 'bootstrap']
        },
        'global': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'metismenu']
        }
    }
};
```

Esse é o meu app.js:

```
require(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'datatables', 'datatablesbootstrap', 'global'], function () {
    $(function () {
        //my code goes here
    });
});
```

Estou recebendo esse erro no console do chrome: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Eu defini o jquery nas dependencias do bootstrap então eu não entendo qual é o problema

Se eu tiro todas as depencias e deixo apenas o jquery na chamada do require ele é reconhecido, porém se eu adiciono qualquer outra dependencia ele deixa de ser reconhecido.

Comment: Testa passar o `$` na callback... assim `..., 'global'], function ($) {`

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver o problema?